# Is there a .NET wrapper for npcap?

Tags: c#, packet-capture

I am trying to replace WinPCap with NpCap. So, I'm looking for the .NET wrapper replacements for the PCapDotnet binaries, which were available for WinPCap (https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net)

I would be using NpCap also in WinPCap mode. In that case, can I continue using the same PcapDotnet binaries for NpCap as well? Or is there any dotnet wrapper available for this?